# Which date format is this NSDate dateFormat?

Tags: swift

I want to convert this string to NSDate,

```
Mon, 21 Mar 2016 10:26:45 GMT
```

so I set the date format to this:

```
dateFormatter.dateFormat = "EEE, dd MMM yyyy HH:mm:ss zzz"
```

but it returns `nil`.

I tried to change this format to:

```
E, dd MMM yyyy HH:mm:ss zzz

EEE, dd MMM yyyy hh:mm:ss zzz

EEE, d MMM yyyy HH:mm:ss zzz
```

but it also returns `nil`.

Which date format should I use?

Comment: Your `dateFormat` looks fine to me (for the given `String` date). How do you attempt to convert the `String` to an `NSDate` instance; are you using `dateFormatter.dateFromString(str)`?

Comment: this is working for me . please check properly .

Comment: Yes, It's working in my playground, but not working in my Xcode project. I'm getting this string value from the server's response header, and trying to convert into NSDate. I'm using alamofire to parse this data.

Comment: @alphonse Eric D.:s answer regarding `NSLocale` will probably fix this for you.

Comment: yeap. it did work :) thank you.

Comment: @dfri NSLocale worked, but it not working if I put NSLocale.currentLocale() . do you know why?

Comment: @alphonse I suspect your `.currentLocale()` (in your project) differs from `"en_us"`. You can try printing out `NSLocale.currentLocale().localeIdentifier` in your project to test this hypothesis.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because Searching reveals 100000 of NSDateFormatter issues that are quite similiar and some are exact dupes

Comment: @Daij-Djan why don't you VTC as dupe instead then?

Comment: @TimCastelijns because I don't see why I need to search :)

Comment: @Daij-Djan I can't tell if you're being sarcastic

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your format string is ok but you have to add a compatible *locale* to the formatter.

For example your string works well with the US locale:

```
let source = "Mon, 21 Mar 2016 10:26:45 GMT"
let dateFormatter = NSDateFormatter()
dateFormatter.locale = NSLocale(localeIdentifier: "en_US")
dateFormatter.dateFormat = "EEE, dd MMM yyyy HH:mm:ss zzz"
let result = dateFormatter.dateFromString(source)
```

Comment: Wow , it is working! But why NSLocale.currentLocale() doesn't work?

Comment: The locale determines how the formatter recognizes words or parts of words. "Mon" means "Monday" so only a "en_US" compatible locale can decode it.

Comment: oh , I see. Then how can I change it to users locale?

Comment: The *result* will be in the user's locale. The one you give here is only to decode the *original* date string.

Answer (score 0):

Try this code block :

```
let dateFormatter = NSDateFormatter()
let dateString = "Mon, 21 Mar 2016 10:26:45 GMT"
dateFormatter.dateFormat = "EEE, dd MMM yyyy HH:mm:ss zzz"
let date = dateFormatter.dateFromString(dateString)
```

Comment: it's working in playground, but not working in my Xcode project. I got this string value from the server using alamofire.

Answer (score -1):

Try escaping the comma:

```
E',' dd MMM yyyy HH:mm:ss zzz
```

Comment: still getting nil... :(

Answer (score -1):

You can try the following code

```
 let dateString:String = "Mon, 21 Mar 2016 10:26:45 GMT"
 let dateFormat = NSDateFormatter.init()
 dateFormat.dateStyle = .FullStyle
 dateFormat.dateFormat = "ccc, dd MM yyyy HH:mm:ss zzz"
 let date:NSDate? = dateFormat.dateFromString(dateString)
 print(dateFormat.stringFromDate(date!))
```

For more info please visit [NSDateFormatter formatting](http://www.alexcurylo.com/blog/2009/01/29/nsdateformatter-formatting/)